# SQL Statement Presumably runs, no errors, but assertion fails

Tags: java, sql, jdbc

So I got this issue where I have to try and book all seats in a flight.

I've made a Helper class with static methods, which is used for Unit Testing purposes. When I run the test though, my bookAll() method runs as so does the "isAllBooked()" method. But the isAllBooked method returns false.

After investigating, it turns out the database was not touched by the initial bookAll() statement at all. But there are no errors. What could be the cause of this?

HelperClass.java

```
public static void bookAll(String plane_no) {
    conn = getConnection("", "");
    try {
        conn.prepareStatement(""
                + "UPDATE SEAT"
                + "SET reserved='1337',booked='1337',booking_time='1337'"
                + "WHERE plane_no='" + plane_no + "';"
        );
        conn.commit();
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        System.out.println("[HELPER CLASS] SQL ERROR: " + ex.getMessage());
    }
    closeConnection(conn);
}

public static boolean isAllBooked(String plane_no) {
    conn = getConnection("", "");
    try {
        ResultSet rs =
                conn.prepareStatement(
                        "SELECT booked FROM SEAT WHERE plane_no='"
                                + plane_no + "'")
                        .executeQuery();
        while(rs.next()) {
            int i = rs.getInt("BOOKED");
            if(rs.wasNull()) {
                closeConnection(conn);
                return false;
            }
        }
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        System.out.println("[HELPER CLASS] SQL ERROR: " + ex.getMessage());
    }
    closeConnection(conn);
    return true;
}
```

HelperClassTest.java

```
@Test
public void testBookAll() {
    System.out.println("bookAll");
    String plane_no = "CR9";
    HelperClass.bookAll(plane_no);
    boolean expResult = true;
    boolean result = HelperClass.isAllBooked(plane_no);
    assertEquals(expResult,result);
}
```

Comment: First thing to fix: stop building SQL manually including the values. Use parameterized SQL.

Comment: This is a test class. It is supposed to have specific values. So unless it got anything to do with actually solving this and not just aesthetics/code ethics, it's hardly related :P

Comment: If it only had specific values, you wouldn't have a `plane_no` parameter. It's *really, really important* to get out of the habit of this horribly-insecure practice.

Comment: If `reserved` is a numeric column you should also avoid assigning string values to it. `'1337'` is a string, `1337` is a number in SQL.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name yes I am aware of that. This is not production code so it's okay to do this.

Comment: I disagree: even if it's not production code it's not OK to do it. Why is it less important to write good code in your tests than in any other code?

Comment: Because this is for dirty prototyping, not production ready code.

Comment: That's okay then.  Because tape-and-string prototype code *never* ends up being deployed into production.  Ever.   ;-)  (But... it is still easier to use a `PreparedStatement`, just for your own convenience and sanity.)

Comment: @Paul Honestly if you develop production ready code when you do basic prototyping, then you are doing it wrong. Prototyping is supposed to be fast and dirty. Not secure, efficient and adhere to code ethics. That takes away the speed in which you can write the prototype.

Comment: I don't do prototyping - 'basic' or otherwise.  Instead, I use programming languages, libraries and tools that allow me write good, minimal, well-tested, well-documented and flexible code (most of it in the form of reusable libraries) quickly.  :-)

Comment: @Paul funny then, that you can make any assertions about Prototype code then :) `That's okay then. Because tape-and-string prototype code never ends up being deployed into production. Ever. ;-)`

Comment: @Vipar Good point.  I should have added "any more" (for precisely the reason you quoted back).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're never *executing* the statement:

```
conn.prepareStatement(""
        + "UPDATE SEAT"
        + "SET reserved='1337',booked='1337',booking_time='1337'"
        + "WHERE plane_no='" + plane_no + "';"
);
conn.commit();
```

You're ignoring the return value of `prepareStatement`, so you're not actually executing anything against the database.

You *should* be creating a `PreparedStatement` using fixed SQL with parameters, specifying parameter values against that `PreparedStatement`, and then call [`PreparedStatement.executeUpdate()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#executeUpdate--).

So something like:

```
public static void bookAll(String planeNo) {
    String sql = "UPDATE SEAT "
               + "SET (reserved, booked, booking_time) "
               + "VALUES ('1337', '1337', '1337') "
               + "WHERE plane_no=?";
    try (Connection conn = getConnection("", "");
         PreparedStatement st = conn.prepareStatement(sql)) {
        st.setString(1, planeNo);
        st.executeUpdate();
        conn.commit();
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        System.out.println("[HELPER CLASS] SQL ERROR: " + ex.getMessage());
    }
}
```

Note that this also:

- Uses a *local* variable for the connection, instead of an instance variable. You should use a separate `Connection` for each operation, even if it's actually pooled
- Uses variable names which comply with Java coding conventions
- Uses a try-with-resources statement to make sure everything is closed even on error

Personally I *wouldn't* use that style of exception handling - I'd let the exception propagate up, possibly rethrowing it as an unchecked exception - but that's a different matter.

Comment: At first it was whining about missing a SET keyword but I figured it out. Will accept when I can. Thanks!

Comment: @Vipar: Once you use a PreparedStatement you should also pass the values for the `set` part as parameters rather than string values.